# I can not display the number of comments

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to display the number of comments (count) on the main page (index page) for articles. I have two models: **comments**, **post** and views **post_detail**, **post_list**. 

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,  db_index=True )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):

  post=models.ForeignKey(Post,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  content= models.TextField(max_length=160)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, slug):

  post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
  comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('id')

  return render(request, {'post': post, 'comments':comments, })
```

```
class PostList(generic.ListView):

    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6
```

On the article page (post_detail), using tag {{comments.count}} the number of comments I receive successfully .  But trying to get the number of comments on posts on the index page (postList), nothing comes of it. I tried {{post.comments.count}} - nothing worked.

Comment: since you did not specify a `related_name=`, it is `{{ post.comment_set.count }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not specify a value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), the related manager to obtain the comments from a `Post` object is `comment_set`. You thus can access the number of comments with:

```
{{ post.comment_set.count }}
```

But this is *not* efficient. It means that for *every* `Post` you here render, you will make an extra query. You better annotate this in the view:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
        ncomment=Count('comment')
    ).filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6
```

The `Post` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.ncomment` that contains the number of comments, so you can render this with:

```
{{ post.ncomment }}
```

Comment: Tell me, if in the template I get input posts from the model such fields as {{post.author} }, {{ post.title }} etc. I also need to optimize them for requests through annotate?

Comment: @new_progger_python: not `title`, since that is a field, so it is fetched in the same query. If `author` is a `ForeignKey` (for example to use `user`) object, you can add a `.select_related('author')` part to the query.

Comment: Can you tell me how to display on the main page, for example, the last 5 comments that were published for all posts?

Comment: Can you tell me how to display on the main page, for example, the last 5 comments that were published for all posts? @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this framework but can't you just send back another property that tells you the length of the comments array which should be the number of comments, like this?

```
return render(request, {
  'post': post,
  'comments': comments,
  'number_of_comments': len(comments)
})
```

Comment: for the most part I needed a tag for the template, the answer helped me at the top - {{ post.comment_set.count }}